# How to close lightning-combobox menu items when scrolling the page in LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds, lightning-combobox

I have a LWC and a lightning-combobox inside it, but while the dropdown items are open and I scroll the page, the menu items are still visible on top of other items. I need to auto-hide the menu items on page scroll. Please help that how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.
HTML CODE

```
<div class="slds-size_1-of-3 slds-grid slds-gutters combobox-alignment">
            <div class="row slds-grid slds-gutters slds-align_absolute-center">
               <span class="slds-m-left_large slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap content-display">
                  <lightning-combobox name="selectednumberlist" value={selected_number_list} options={selectedOptions}
                     onchange={handleChange} variant="label-hidden" dropdown-alignment="auto" class="combobox-width">
                  </lightning-combobox>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
```

JS CODE

```
    @track selected_number_list = '10';

    get selectedOptions() {
        return [
            { value: '10', label: '10'},
            { value: '25', label: '25'},
            { value: '50', label: '50'},
            { value: '75', label: '75'},
            { value: '100', label: '100'}
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.selected_number_list = event.detail.value;
    }
```

The following is the screenshot of the problem being faced
[image: Overlapping Issue]

Comment: It shall go away on its own when you select one option or click outside or focus on another element on the page.  Is there any reason why you want to hide that on scroll?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes, it works fine if a selection is made or clicking anywhere outside. But the issue is, "If the dropdown list is open and someone scroll it". At this point, we are facing this issue and QA team wants it to be fixed :(, though it might rarely be encountered.

Comment: You can fix this, first inspect and get the styles to be applied, then add those styles to a static resource, then load resource using `loadstyle` in LWC. But keep in mind that this CSS will be applicable to all of the components. So be specific with CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue with combobox. I gave it below fix. you can provide onwheel event in HTML of your LWc and in its handler put the below code

```
OnscrollHandler(event) {
   if(window.pageYOffset > 0) {
   //show hide your dropdown by boolean flags
   this.showalloptions = false;
   this.showoptions = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onfocus` attribute to your lightning combobox. Then you can create a method like `handleFocus`. Inside this method, you need to add an event listener to the parent component or window.

P.S. Of course you can add it on conncetedCallback, it depends on your case).

```
Example:

this.template.querySelector('<queryElementYouNeed>').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   let combobox = this.template.querySelector("<queryLightningCombobox>");

   //blur method will close dropdown menu.
    combobox.blur()
});
```